# How do I change the font size according to screen size

Tags: ios, fonts, autolayout, uilabel, constraints

I have added min font size to label but the font is not changing according to the screen size.

I thought setting min font size and using autolayout is to scale the label height is enough.

But its not happening.

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of your view with the label?

Comment: Its just a rectangular view that has a label from ten px trailing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use minimum font scale instead of minimum font size. Minimum font size was deprecated in IOS 6. In the image although mine says fixed here you can change that and then set the scale factor.

To vary by size of the screen you can do some of that with interface builder. See image. This is using size classes.
[image: AddFontSize]

Other ways would be to increase the font size to a large number and let it scale, set it in code by device type, or set a constraint on the label to make it grow and shrink between different sizes and have the scaling set right.

Comment: So according to screen size ... How will it change the font size ?

Comment: Thanks .  How to set constraint on label to let it grow or shrink ?

Comment: Drag from label to superview and use equal width and change the multiplier from 1 to desired percentage.  0.5 = 50% of the super width or drag from uilabel to superview and choose aspect ratio

Comment: Yes.  the steps in the answer help the scaling of the font.  Constraining the label size would help you use IB to change the font size through out.  You would set the font really big and scaling factor to allow it to scale down.

Comment: Ok thanks ... You have any idea on how to use adaptive text fonts to achieve this ? If yes ...plz tell me how to do ?

Comment: for resizing what I put above is how it works.  You can add fonts for variations in size classes

Comment: If you don't mind,can I have your google hangout id or something ...so that next time when I post question i can let u know and I admire your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

TextKit provides the inbuilt support for making UI with Adaptive text font sizing based on auto layouts.

https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/

Check the details on Dynamic text on above article.

Comment: Can you explain me with a sample plz

Comment: Join the group Design + Code on Facebook and post there and I will see it and I will shoot you a friend request

Answer (score 0):

```swift
extension UIFont {
    
    class func dynamicFontSizeWithName(fontName: String, fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        /*
         You can replace 320 with the value you desire based on what resolution the screen is designed in. Here are the values you can replace 414 with, based on the phone:
         E.g :
         iPhone 6, 7, 8 Plus — 414
         iPhone  X — 375
         */
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let calculatedFontSize = screenWidth / 414 * fontSize
        return UIFont(name: fontName, size: calculatedFontSize)!
    }
}
```

Example:

```
label.font = UIFont.dynamicFontSizeWithName(fontName:.......
```